# OraclePreparedStatementWrapper cannot be cast to java.sql.CallableStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to call oracle db function by java as following :

```
StoredProcedureCall getTaxProcedureCall = new StoredProcedureCall();
getTaxProcedureCall.setProcedureName("getTaxByCustomerId");  
getTaxProcedureCall.addNamedArgument("ImpactedParty"); 
getTaxProcedureCall.addNamedArgument("ImpactedPartyType"); 


getTaxProcedureCall.addNamedOutputArgument("P_TAX");
getTaxProcedureCall.addNamedOutputArgument("A_TAX");

DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery();
query.setCall(getTaxProcedureCall);
query.addArgument("ImpactedParty");
query.addArgument("ImpactedPartyType");

Vector queryValues = new Vector();
queryValues.add(cusId);
queryValues.add("CSID");

Vector<DatabaseRecord> records = (Vector<DatabaseRecord>)TransactionContext.getCurrent().getUnitOfWork().executeQuery(query, queryValues);
return records;
```

but when run it, it gave : oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper cannot be cast
     to java.sql.CallableStatement

at `Vector<DatabaseRecord> records = (Vector<DatabaseRecord>)TransactionContext.getCurrent().getUnitOfWork().executeQuery(query, queryValues);`

Comment: make sure your ojdbc jar is inside lib folder of your project

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace and identify what `StoredProcedureCall`,`DataReadQuery` and `TransactionContext` are (ie: what library). If they are your own code, then you should include them. But the most obvious explanation is that somewhere down the line a `PreparedStatement` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by replacing `StoredProcedureCall` with `SQLCall`

and pass sql string like:
`SELECT getTaxByCustomerId(#ImpactedParty, #ImpactedPartyType, #TaxProfile) AS P_TAX FROM DUAL`

now it's work fine.